# combining two if statements

Tags: python

I am trying to combine the following if statments

```
    if "%s\n" % baseAU in out:
        print "Match"
        count = 1

    if internaldep in pendinggerrits:
        print "match"
        count = 1
```

I tried the following but is there an easier way

```
    if  "%s\n" % baseAU in out and internaldep in pendinggerrits:
        print "match"
```

Comment: What exactly is "not easy" about that?

Comment: Incidentally, those two versions are *NOT* equivalent. The first version is `or` logic, while the second one is `and` logic.

Comment: Your two sets of statements are not equivalent. Your first two "if" statements are independent.  In the second case, you apply "and" to the two conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't an "easier way" to put two conditions in an `if` statement; the way that you already have is pretty concise.

(Note, however, that the combined version does not do the same thing as the original version. You'd want to use `or` instead of `and` for that.)

Answer (score 2):

Your second statement is not equal to first two.
Notice that 'match' is printed if any of those 2 if blocks is satisfied.

But in your concise version, you are using `and` operator, `match` will be printed only when BOTH OF THEM ARE TRUE.

If you intend to do what you did with 2 independent blocks, you need to use `OR` :

```
 if  "%s\n" % baseAU in out or internaldep in pendinggerrits:
        print "match"
```

and yes, this is the cleanest and simplest way to combine those blocks.